# R nested loop slow

Tags: performance, r

I have no idea why something like this should be slow:

```
steps=500
samples=100000
s_0=2.1
r=.02
sigma=.2
k=1.9

at<-matrix(nrow=(steps+1),ncol=samples)
at[1,]=s_0

for(j in 1:samples)
{
  for(i in 2:(steps+1))
  {
    at[i,j]=at[(i-1),j] + sigma*sqrt(.0008)*rnorm(1)
  }
}
```

I tried to rewrite this using sapply, but it was still awful from a performance standpoint.

Am I missing something here? This would be seconds in c++ or even the bloated c#.

Comment: R != C++. Many R function are vectorized (they work on entire objects in one function call) and you're throwing all that performance out the window.

Comment: I hear that, but then shouldn't sapply be better? Or can you teach me the ways of R?

Comment: `sapply` ignores vectorization too.  It's basically a loop at the C-level, but you still have all the R function calls.  I'll take a shot at "doing it right", but I'm still waiting for your slow example to finish running. :)

Comment: Can't you move `sigma*sqrt(.0008)*rnorm(1)` outside the loop? I have no idea what r is, but that seems bad.

Comment: oh, kill it. you will wait all day.  if you want to see it work as an example drop samples down to something like 1,000.

Comment: pete->no. since the next value of the vector relies on the computation of the last.

Comment: Ya know, Joshua, this sort of sequential task cries out for a builtin R function. It just doesn't work with the usual vectorization approaches that expect the prior sequential value to be in the original complete object, when it is in fact supposed to be altered. I've seen code with the `filter` function, but I didn't really grok the method. There is also `Reduce` which might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R can vectorize certain operations. In your case you can get rid of the outer loop by doing a following change.

```
for(i in 2:(steps + 1))
{
    at[i,] = at[(i - 1),] + sigma * sqrt(.0008) * rnorm(samples)
}
```

According to `system.time` the original version for `samples = 1000` takes 6.83s, while the modified one 0.09s.

Comment: I guess you mean `rnorm(samples)`?

Comment: that doesn't produce the same results as the code above. I agree I think it was implied rnorm(samples).

Comment: Oops, just realised. Too quick to write before thinking! :) You got it right.

Comment: can someone catch me up here. If I use rnorm(samples), I get the correct result, where as rnorm(1) does not produce the intended result.

Comment: I guess my point is, if I use rnorm(1), I get the same random value for the entire row, where what I really want is different random numbers for every column in the row, hence rnorm(samples)

Comment: Ah, now I see. Good catch! I'll update the answer. @Arun, you were right, thanks once again!

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
at <- s_0 + t(apply(matrix(rnorm(samples*(steps+1),sd=sigma*sqrt(8e-4)),
                   ncol=samples),
                    2,
                    cumsum))
```

(Haven't tested this carefully yet, but I think it should be right, and much faster.)

Comment: (+1) This is the approach that should be taken.

Comment: This will probably work for `cumprod` type questions as well.

Answer (score 1):

To write fast R code, you really need to re-think how you write functions. You want to operate on entire vectors, not just single observations at a time.

If you're really deadset in writing C-style loops, you could also try out Rcpp. Could be handy if you're well accustomed to C++ and prefer writing functions that way.

```
library(Rcpp)
do_stuff <- cppFunction('NumericMatrix do_stuff(
  int steps,
  int samples,
  double s_0,
  double r,
  double sigma,
  double k ) {

  // Ensure RNG scope set
  RNGScope scope;

  // allocate the output matrix
  NumericMatrix at( steps+1, samples );

  // fill the first row
  for( int i=0; i < at.ncol(); i++ ) {
    at(0, i) = s_0;
  }

  // loop over the matrix and do stuff
  for( int j=0; j < samples; j++ ) {
    for( int i=1; i < steps+1; i++ ) {
      at(i, j) = at(i-1, j) + sigma * sqrt(0.0008) * R::rnorm(0, 1);
    }
  }

  return at;

}')

system.time( out <- do_stuff(500, 100000, 2.1, 0.02, 0.2, 1.9) )
```

gives me

```
   user  system elapsed 
  3.205   0.092   3.297
```

So, if you've already got some C++ background, consider learning how to use Rcpp to map data to and from R.

Comment: wow, good to know.  I'm trying to learn R the "right" way, but sometimes I'm in a time crunch and need to fall back on old ways.  Good to know this exist as a safety net.